# Combination of a single request into a bulk request API PYTHON

Tags: python, json, api

I have a request that is in a loop to the API, but I want to optimize the speed of execution and switch to sending bulk requests.

There is pagination in the API, from which we download 25 records per page, and this is exactly the limit in the bulk operation, you can also send up to 25 single requests in one bulk action.

Example of last page:

```
{
'count':'273',
'pages':11,
'page':11,
'list':[
{'product_id':'18391',
'producer_id':'3257',
'stock':{
    'stock': '0'
}
},
{'product_id':'18392',
'producer_id':'3257',
'stock':{
    'stock': '0'
}}
]
}
```

There is code in loop to send data:

```
data = {
    "stock": {
        "stock": "0"
    }
}

y = 0
for page in get_jobs():
    try:
        print(page)
        for off in json.loads(turnoff_product_request.text)['list']:
            code = page['list'][y]['product_id'].replace('"', '')
            api_url = "https://example.com/webapi/rest/products/%s" % code
            add_product = requests.request("PUT", api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
            y += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        y = 0
    except Exception:
        print(Exception)
        pass
```

And now is example how to use bulk request. ***% code - must be dynamically inserted based on product_id***:

```
[
  {
    "id": "doesnt matter id, can be every 1 or something",
    "path": "/webapi/rest/products/%s" % code,
    "method": "PUT",
    "body": {
       "stock": {
         "stock": "0"
       }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "doesnt matter id, can be every 1 or something",
    "path": "/webapi/rest/products/%s" % code,
    "method": "PUT",
    "body": {
       "stock": {
         "stock": "0"
       }
    }
  },
]
```

I have no idea, how i can group this products, where pages 1-10 have 25 items, and last page may contain fewer products

Comment: can you explain your question clearly?

Comment: @deadshot i mean how send result from response at 1st code example into request (3 code) where i need to send productid as code

Comment: you can use `f-strings` or `string.format()`